# Media Custom Fields - get a value with PHP

Tags: custom-field, media, media-library

How to get a value of a field set with [Media Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-custom-fields/) (programmatically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-custom-fields/faq/

> **How does this plugin handle my data?**
>
> Media items are stored in
>   WordPress just like regular posts. This enables us to use native
>   WordPress functions to store and retrieve your custom fields. Due to
>   this, your data is stored in a very future-proof way, in the postmeta
>   table of the WordPress database.

So you would do it the same way you would do it for a post or page using `get_post_meta`, but you would pass the media attachment ID in as the post ID